# File tab menu font on Notepad++ with Windows 10

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, can I modify the FILE TAB fonts? Not the code being edited, but the tabs that show the filenames. Lighter grey on grey is not working for me.

This is a snippet of what I am asking about:

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change these style quite easily. Firstly click settings and Style Configurator. In the global styles list look for the following attributes in the style list menu:

[image: Notepad++ Style Configurator]

Comment: Does this really work? Font size control is inactive to change for me and also in this screenshot.

Comment: No, it does not. It did not when this answer was posted in 2016, nor does it at my time of writing in 2022.